# Alternative for Aws::S3::Presigner#presigned_request in aws-sdk v3 in aws-sdk v2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Ruby aws-sdk v3 is having [presigned_request method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Presigner.html#presigned_request-instance_method) in Aws::S3::Presigner class. It is used for signing a request. But in aws-sdk v2, the [presign_request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v2/api/Aws/S3/Presigner.html) is not available. I am trying to sign additional headers for the presigned URLs. Is there a way?

Comment: [trying-to-generate-a-presigned-url-link-so-an-user-can-download-an-amazon-s3-obj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29313235/2246345) and the corresponding gist [pre-signed GET url](https://gist.github.com/trevorrowe/49bfb9d59f83ad450a9e). The idea is kind of same and revolves around Aws::Signers

Comment: @samtoddler please look my response in the answer

Comment: URL generated now seems fine, check your client code which is sending the headers, the error message is same as earlier we had , whatever we signed is not being set at the client side while making the request.

Comment: @samtoddler please look my response in the answer

Answer (score 0):

@Samtoddler

The main purpose of this problem to additionally sign 'x-amz-tagging' for a :put request presigned url, I tried to modify your code by adding additional header

```
class Aws::Signers::V4
  def presigned_url(request, options = {})
    now = Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")
    body_digest = options[:body_digest] || hexdigest(request.body)

    request.headers.delete('User-Agent')
    request.headers['Host'] = request.endpoint.host

    params = Aws::Query::ParamList.new
    params.set("X-Amz-Algorithm", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256")
    params.set("X-Amz-Credential", credential(now))
    params.set("X-Amz-Date", now)
    params.set("X-Amz-Expires", options[:expires_in].to_s)
    params.set("X-Amz-SignedHeaders", signed_headers(request))
    params.set("X-Amz-Tagging", 'param=value')
    params.set('X-Amz-Security-Token', credentials.session_token) if
      credentials.session_token

    endpoint = request.endpoint
    if endpoint.query
      endpoint.query += '&' + params.to_s
    else
      endpoint.query = params.to_s
    end
    endpoint.to_s + '&X-Amz-Signature=' + signature(request, now, body_digest)
  end
end
```

When i tried this, the url which i obtained is having "X-Amz-tagging" header:

```
https://xxxxxxxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/mypath/myfile.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJILKMM53N2D4HKKA%2F20210114%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210114T154613Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm%3Bx-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key%3Bx-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key-md5&X-Amz-Tagging=param%3Dvalue&X-Amz-Signature=f7f4c5752cb181bf0d8d1134b4a9add9ecad15116f26dd5979b992db87060498
```

But when i tried to make a request from my client, i am getting an saying:

```
There were headers present in the request which were not signed
<HeadersNotSigned>x-amz-tagging</HeadersNotSigned>
```

Answer (score 0):

@samtoddler

This is how am setting in the client side

```
ObjectiveService.postFilesToAWS = function (presigned_url, file, headers={}) {
    return $http({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: presigned_url,
      ignoreLoadingBar: true,
      data: file,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': file.type,
        'X-Amz-Tagging': 'param=value'
      }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      return response;
    }, function (error) {
      return error;
    });
  }
```

The same client code is working for aws-sdk v3 in #presigned_request method.

Answer (score 0):

So far what I read is that the header in the error message might not be the problem, it could be with any other header as well missing or not having the appropriate values set.

Are you using [Specifying server-side encryption with AWS KMS (SSE-KMS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/specifying-kms-encryption.html)
 or [server-side encryption with customer-provided encryption keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/specifying-s3-c-encryption.html) because things are different, I see headers being present for SSE-C but the values are not specified.

for example this header **x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-algorithm** in the URL is present

> https://xxxxxxxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/mypath/myfile.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJILKMM53N2D4HKKA/20210114/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210114T154613Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm;x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key;x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key-md5&X-Amz-Tagging=param=value&X-Amz-Signature=f7f4c5752cb181bf0d8d1134b4a9add9ecad15116f26dd5979b992db87060498

the value should be **AES256** as the documentation.

Your generated URL should be something like this

> "https://.s3.amazonaws.com/?X-Amz-Security-Token=&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20180718T013339Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type%253Bhost&X-Amz-Expires=1799&X-Amz-Credential=&X-Amz-Signature=

I would suggest giving [AWS Signature Version 4 Signature Calculation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html#example-signature-calculations) a read to get the idea and which headers should be present.